# How to split a huge text dataset in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, dataset

the first part of my Machine learning project is splitting the huge dataset into 3 parts, and then use them as training data sets and test data set. this dataset includes 10milion rows like the following:

[image]

The above picture is the screenshot of my dataset. I don't want to change the order of columns or rows, so the random doesn't work here. As you can see, they are 6 columns that separated by a tab and includes 10milion of rows. I want to split these rows into 3 separate parts, which the first 3333333.333 rows are my dataset1 and then the second 3333333.333 rows are the dataset2 and the rest is the dataset3. so 3 different text files that the order of components(columns) were not changed.
 I am using Spyder3 and I wrote the following codes by your help:

```
f = open ( 'pr_data.txt' , 'r')  """Reading File"""

l = [ map(float,line.strip().split()) for line in f ]

no_samples = len(l)

data1 = l[0:int(no_samples/3)][:]

data2 = l[int(no_samples/3):int(no_samples*2/3)][:]

data3 = l[int(no_samples*2/3):no_samples][:]

file = open('data1.txt','w')
for row in data1: 
    file.writelines(["%s\t" % item for item in row]) 
    file.writelines("\n") 
file.close()

file = open('data2.txt','w')
for row in data2: 
    file.writelines(["%s\t" % item for item in row]) 
    file.writelines("\n") 
file.close()

file = open('data3.txt','w')
for row in data3: 
    file.writelines(["%s\t" % item for item in row]) 
    file.writelines("\n") 
file.close()
```

by the above code, the 3 text file is created in the same directory, but the problem is: the precision of numbers is changed. for example, 0's and 1's are changed to 0.0 and 1.0. Also, some of them are not in the same column. Please see the screenshot of the first rows of data1, in the following:
[image]

Please let me know how correct my code?

Comment: How do you want to split the file? Random splits?

Comment: Also, you do not need to close the file when using with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. no, not randomly. As you can see in the screenshot of my dataset, they are 6 columns that separated by a tab and includes 10milion of rows. I want to split these rows into 3 separate parts, which the first 3333333.333 rows are my dataset1 and then the second 3333333.333 rows are the dataset2 and the rest is the dataset3. so 3 different text files that the order of components(columns) were not changed.

Comment: And don't forget to indent the lines after the `with...`

Comment: Please see the edited question and compare the screenshot of data1 with the screenshot of the original dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the approach would be as follows:

1. Open the file
2. While reading the file line by line split each line using the split() method. Also while splitting also convert the string obtained into float.
3. Now you have the whole file as a multidimensional array of the type float.
4. Obtain the number of samples(rows).
5. Using slicing store rows from 0 to rows/3 in the first data, rows/3 to rows*2/3 in data2 and the remaining rows in data3.

```js
f = open ( 'input.txt' , 'r')
l = [ map(float,line.strip().split()) for line in f ]

no_samples = len(l)

data1 = l[0:int(no_samples/3)][:]

data2 = l[int(no_samples/3):int(no_samples*2/3)][:]

data3 = l[int(no_samples*2/3):no_samples][:]

//Write a multidimensional list to a file
file = open('data1.txt','w')
for row in data1: 
    file.writelines(["%s\t" % item for item in row]) 
    file.writelines("\n") 
file.close()
```

Comment: great explanation.it runs untill "no_attrs = len(f[0])". when i run this line, then I get this error:"TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: ok. I removed that line and all other lines perfectly run. now, data1 should include the first 1/3 of all 10milion rows, data2 include the second 1/3 and data3 include the rest of rows. how can I write data1,data2,data3? 3 different text files in the same directory.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. One way is to use the numpy package and convert the multidimensional list into a 2D numpy array and then simply use numpy.savetxt(filename, 2D numpy array) for each of the file. One other way I have shown in the code that I have edited.

Comment: the 3 text files are created but they are empty, also I got this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 0.65258 0.52520 0.95356 0.14795 0.36442 1\n'

Comment: I changed how I was reading the file a bit. I am not specifying any parameter for splitting. I tried it on a simple example and it is working fine now. Take a look at the edited code.

Comment: Thank you so much. you perfectly Solved this problem. I voted your answer as the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Please see the edited question and compare the screenshot of data1 with the screenshot of the original dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Print needs normal brackets -> ()
Change your code to:

```
print(data.read())
```

If you are handling the data as a string (which you are in this example), you should first just split it at every new line with `data.split("\n")`. This will return a list with every line.

EDIT:
Now you can slice that list to get 3 separate lists:

```
data1 = lines[0:1/3*len(lines)]
data2 = lines[1/3*len(lines):2/3*len(lines)]
data3 = lines[2/3*len(lines):len(lines)]
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. I corrected it but when I execute the print code, I get this error: "NameError: name 'data' is not defined"

Comment: Did you change anything else in your code? `data` should exist inside the `with` block.

Comment: after splitting, they will be my train and test datasets. I should apply the discrete Bayesian rule, Entropy, decision rule, quantization ... on that. So these rows won't be a string and I should find the probability of each number in each column. but the first step is dividing them into 3 separate datasets that I have used python for that. if windows can do it easier than Python please let me know.

Comment: I edited the answer. If you want to turn the lists back into strings now, you can just call `"\n".join(data1)`. This will create a string with "\n" between every entry from the list.

Comment: before slicing `lines` you need to define it with `lines = data.split("\n")`

Comment: Please see the edited question and compare the screenshot of data1 with the screenshot of the original dataset.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem: \t is not always the same size. It's every 4 characters. And 3.40 is equal to 3.4